# iMac fan going on and off

Tags: mac, fan

We have an iMac at our house which hasn't been turned on for about two month. I've turned it on and I'm getting some updates done, but the iMac fan is behaving weirdly. It goes full speed, and then stops, and then goes at full speed again, at random intervals. It's almost like the CPU thinks the machine is overheating but is hesitant to put the fans on full power.

The fans would go on full power for about 3 seconds, and then keep quite, and then go at it again. I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I have my Macbook in the same room, and it's running as smooth as ever. Is a security compromise a possibility here?